# Replacing straight quotes with curly quotes as a basic setting in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editing, translation

I'm doing translation work and I have to use curly quotes because the web developers behind the site I'm working for had some bugs with straight quotes that interfered with their work. Now I could of course type Alt+0147 and Alt+0148 every time I use quotes, but it takes an enormous amount of time. Is there any way I could automatically switch them, where I'd always type curly quotes except if I specifically choose to type straight ones?

Poedit for example doesn't have a setting to automatically change them like Microsoft Word does, which is a large loss of time.

Comment: You could bind keys/key-combinations to “ and ”, but I suspect it's not possible change the " key character in Windows to do 2 things depending on context.

Comment: That could indeed be a solution, now how do I do that ? :) I'm a translator, not a developper...

Comment: It's possible to set up that bindings *by hand* via some (non-trivial) registry manipulation however [AutoIt](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) offers user-friendly tool for it.

Comment: I'm gonna try that and find out if it works ! thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Autohotkey](http://ahkscript.org/).

Use this script:

```
#SingleInstance force

+2::
    Send {“}
return

+!2::
    Send {”}
return
```

"+" means shift. "!" means alt.
Shift+2 now sends open curly. Alt+Shift+2 now sends close curly. This will affect all applications whilst the script is running. (Exit autohotkey from system tray to stop)

Customise as you see fit:
# = Windows logo key
! = Alt 
^ = Control 
+ = Shift

Comment: I'm gonna try that and find out if it works ! thanks !

Comment: Just tried it and it works like a charm! thanks so much ! “”

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I'm using:

```
#SingleInstance force

+^"::
    Send {“}
return

+!"::
    Send {”}
return

^'::
    Send {‘}
return

!'::
    Send {’}
return

#'::
    Send {′}
return

+#'::
    Send {″}
return
```

This avoids having to reach for number keys, and works OK with either left or right side chord-keying. Shift works as normal, just add:

```
CTRL        for opening marks
ALT         for closing marks
WINDOWS     for prime marks
```

Question for the developer or superusers:

Is there a scripting syntax for treating repeated keystroke as discrete hotkeys?

Perhaps some users would rather not remember multiple hotkeys. Repetition could work:

For ' (regular apostrophe), just use the '/" key as usual; for ‘ (smart open) tap it twice, while holding down your self-defined hotkey; three times for ’ (smart close). Add shift, as usual, to get quotation marks... but now your *one hotkey smartifies* everything. This might be more intuitive, especially for non-superusers—just tap to cycle through the smart mark options.

Is that notional usage supported?

Answer (score 0):

- You don’t *say* what editor you’re using,
  or specifically what context you’re talking about.
- If you want this to work universally throughout Windows
  (including, for example, in CMD and Notepad), you’re probably out of luck.
- You mention “Poedit”, which I’ve never heard of. 
  Does it have a search-and-replace function?

I propose a two-stage solution:

**Stage A**: Simply type <kbd>"</kbd>
and get a document full of straight quotes.

When you come to a good stopping point (e.g., end of a chapter,
end of a day’s work, or definitely before giving the document to anybody, …

**Stage B**: Change the straight quotes to curly quotes.

Two approaches:

1. Search for `"` (straight quote) and replace with `“` (left curly quote). 
   When you find the first one,
   hit “Replace” or “Yes” or whatever your editor offers you. 
   When you find the second one, hit “Skip” (or whatever). 
   Do this (alternating responses) throughout the document,
   keeping an eye out for issues.

   Then, when you get to the end, go back to the beginning,
   and search for `"` (straight quote)
   and replace with `”` (right curly quote). 
   It’s probably safe to do “Replace All” now.

   Obviously,
   this requires that you go through the entire document semi-manually. 
   It can be tedious if the document has a lot of quotes,
   and can be error-prone. 
   But you need to type Alt+0147 and Alt+0148 only once each
   (per day, or per chapter, or whatever). 
   And, if you’re paying attention,
   it gives you the opportunity to catch errors
   (e.g., where you typed only one of a pair of quotes)
   or special cases that the second approach (below) might get wrong.
2. Search for `␣"` and replace with `␣“`
   (where `␣` represents a space). 
   (As before, you are replacing straight quotes with left curly quotes.) 
   Do “Replace All”.

   Then repeat with

   - `Tab"` → `Tab“` 
     (assuming your editor supports this)
   - `("` → `(“`
   - `["` → `[“`
   - `{"` → `{“`

   (Skip any of the above that you know don’t apply to your document.)

   And finally,
   search for `"` (straight quote) and replace with `“` (left curly quote)
   when it occurs at the beginning of a line / paragraph. 
   The exact technique for doing this will vary between editors.

   Then go back to the beginning, search for `"` (straight quote)
   and replace with `”` (right curly quote), and do “Replace All”.

   This seems to be, approximately, what Microsoft Word does. 
   It seems like a bit (or a *lot*?) less work than the first approach,
   but you should probably proofread the resulting document very carefully
   to look for special cases.

---

All of the above can be applied to single quotes (`'` vs `‘` and `’`) also.